# In R dplyr, rename a value based on its value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am sure this has been asked before but would really appreciate any help as I am a bit confused.

In R, I have a dataframe with rows for plants' Latin names and their common names. Using dplyr, I want to change the common name if the Latin name equals something specific.

i.e. if Latin_name == 'xyz', rename Common_name to 'abc'

I think I know how to do it with the mutate() function, but this adds an entire new column - I'd prefer to rename the values in the original column. Any help would be great, thank you so much.

Comment: I think what you mean is to recode the variable, rather than rename? In dplyr lingo rename() is specifically for column names.

Comment: `mutate(Common_name = if_else(Latin_name == "xyz", "abc", Common_name))`? Otherwise, please share an extract of your data (using `dput(data)`) and the code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you this has worked. I didn't realise mutate could be used in this way! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
your_data %>%
  mutate(Common_name = case_when(
    Latin_name == 'xyz' ~ 'abc',
    TRUE ~ Common_name)
  )
```

In base R:

```
your_data[your_data$Latin_name == 'xyz', 'Common_name'] <- 'abc'
```